# Смена статуса боту Discord API

Tags: http, post, discord, discord-api

Пишу элементарного бота для дискорда. Я использую запросы Post и Get.

> Get: /users/@me // Я получаю информацию о себе
>
> Post: /channels/id/messages + JSON // Отправка сообщений

... и тд

Как изменить свой статус? Ознакомился [https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro,но](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro,%D0%BD%D0%BE) так и не понял на какой путь отправить запрос.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй:

`````
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status= discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Game('сюда пиши что-нибудь') )````
`````

Comment: Ilya Gorbunov Спасибо, но это у Вас через библиотеку (на питоне вроде). А мне вариант нужен когда я сам через Post запрос шлю команду.

Answer (score 0):

Ilya Gorbunov Спасибо, но это у Вас через библиотеку (на питоне вроде). А мне вариант нужен когда я сам через Post запрос шлю команду.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Понял что патч запрос надо слать на:
**https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/settings**
В ответ получаю **403 Forbidden**, что я как понял означает отсутствие прав. Но какие права нужны, если бот и так мой, и я меняю в нем статус?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).